# pyqt application needs to run with administrator rights

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, pyinstaller

I have a pyqt application which needs to run with admin rights since it creates some network connections. I have it packaged and working but my users (I bet) will forget to right-click and "Run as administrator" so is there a way in either pyqt or pyinstaller to enforce this thing and make sure the app runs with admin rights?

Comment: thats only for unix:

`os.geteuid()¶
Return the current process’s effective user id.

Availability: Unix.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom manifest file specifying the required [requestedExecutionLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) with the same name as the final .exe filename and run *PyInstaller* with the `--manifest` option.

Answer (score 2):

run **PyInstaller** with the `--uac-admin` option

[docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-uac-admin)